# EntityTypeConfiguration property method by reflection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

```
public class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfiguration()
    {
        Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("ProductName");
    }
}
```

I have a product configuration of entity framework. I want to use this by reflection.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        foreach (var assembly in   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => 
                      a.GetName().Name != "EntityFramework"))
                {
                    var configTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t =>
                        t.BaseType != null &&
                        t.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
                        t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));

                    foreach (var configType in configTypes)
                    {
                        if (configType.BaseType == null) continue;

                         ??????Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("ProductName");
                         ??????
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: *I want to use this by reflection.* - you mean, you want to add configurations at `OnModelCreating` dynamically?

Comment: I edited post onModelCreating

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

After finding all configurations you need to create *instance* of them and add them to `modelBuilder.Configurations`:

```
foreach (var configType in configTypes)
{
    if (configType.BaseType == null) continue;

     dynamic configInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(configType);
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configInstance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to go through the trouble of using reflection, EF has already done it for you :)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(ProductConfiguration).Assembly);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```